# Form POST into Curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a form created with 2 fields and a submit button. But i want to do the same thing using Curl.

i tried it by using following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

`$fields` included the two fields.

but the required output never came.

is there a way to do this successfully?

Comment: Make sure that curl extension is enabled on your server.

Comment: You need to help us help you. Please provide more information, for example, what exactly has been assigned to `$fields`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, be sure to set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to TRUE if the url supplied redirects at all using a Location: header....

Answer (score 0):

To get output set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER in TRUE:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `$fields` must be like this:

```
$fields = "user=".$_POST['user']"&password=".$_POST['password'];
```

In my case, my fields called user and password.
Second, in order to see returned result, you have to set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```